# Magento2 - How to configure PayPal Website Payments Pro Hosted and it's support 3D secure?

Tags: magento2, paypal-pro, 3d-secure

I am using `Magento2.3.3 EE`.

Payment country is `UK`. I want to configured PayPal Website Payments Pro Hosted  solution method in `Magento2`.

Does it support `3D secure`? How to teat it?

I have read below docs but its seems found for `PWA/Graphql`.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/payment-methods/hosted-pro.html

Have anyone implemented before can you please help me.